# python console closes before it starts

Tags: python, console

I am learning Python and came across this problem. I know that i can put "input()" at the bottom of the program, but the problem is that it IS there, but console terminates nevertheless. It seems like the programm never starts at all. I am using the 3.5 version of Python.

Comment: What are you trying to run and how are you running it? Is this on Windows/mac/linux?

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal, navigate to the directory of your file, and type `python myfile.py`. If you just double click the file in your system explorer it will run and close when it finishes, which is often too fast to see what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are starting the programme  by clicking on it don't do that to run your programme follow following steps

1.open command prompt
2. go to the path where you have your python programme
3. use command for python for eg: python programme.py in linux
4. if it says python command not recognised probably because the path to python executable is not present in system path add it to environment variable and that should work fine